# Запятая после слов «куда и зачем»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Тем временем мы продолжаем идти. Куда и зачем, я так и не понял, но у меня не было особо других вариантов.

Здесь все правильно? После «куда и зачем» нужна запятая, верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна, это СПП: **Куда и зачем (мы продолжаем идти), я так и не понял.**

"Особо другие варианты" — ошибка, "особо не было" — встречается в бытовой речи, но тоже ошибка.

Answer (score 4):

**Тем временем мы продолжаем идти. Куда и зачем, я так и не понял, но у меня не было особо (много) других вариантов.**

**Пояснения**

1) Изъяснительная часть ***куда и зачем***  **в препозиции** должна быть выделена.

Сравнить: Мы долго шли, но я не понял **куда и зачем**. Здесь нет обособления, так как изъяснительная часть представлена только союзными словами.

Можно использовать **тире**, если сделать паузу для интонационного выделения: **Куда и зачем ― я так и не понял**...

2) ***Не было особо других вариантов*** ― **разговорная** (неточная) грамматика.

**Особо, наречие.** О. важный, трудный. О. опасный преступник. Хищения в о. крупных размерах. О дальнейших планах поговорим о.

Правильнее сказать: **особо (очень) много вариантов.**